# How to kill a jupyter lab cell with a for-try-except block?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a cell in jupyter lab:

```
for _ in range(40):
    try:
        print('Hello')
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass
```

I need to implement some function inside a try-except block. However, for such code, I am not able to kill the process. Each interrupt raised via the `stop` button in jupyter lab sends a SIGINT (eqv. to Ctrl-C) which uses it to escape the try-except block and not the for-loop. How do I stop the execution of the entire cell. Are there other interrupts possible to give to jupyter.

Comment: You really shouldn't have used a blanket `except` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First figure out which Exception is thrown when you are killing the cell. I used a `1/0` as a demo to throw an error.

```
for _ in range(40):
    try:
        print('Hello')
        time.sleep(1)
        a = 1/0
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e))
```

Then catch that one seperately:

```
for _ in range(40):
    try:
        print('Hello')
        time.sleep(1)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

`ZeroDivisionError` should be what is printed by the first block.